# Combinatorics Coloring numbers

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

Let $n\ge2$ be a positive integer. We say that a positive integer $N \ge n$ is nice if, for every coloring
of the positive integers $n, n + 1, n + 2, . . ., N$ in two colors, there always exists three numbers $a$, $b$, and $c$ among
them (not necessarily distinct) which all have the same color and which satisfy $a^b = c$. Find the smallest nice
positive integer $N$.

I have figured out that the smallest value of $N$ is probably $n^{n^{n+2}}$. Call the two colors red and blue. WLOG, let $n$ be red, which then forces $n^n$ to be blue. We then have ${n^n}^{n^n}=n^{n^{n+1}}$ as red. Also, $n^{n+1}$ must be blue otherwise $n,n^{n+1},n^{n^{n+1}}$ would be a triplet. Now, $(n^{n^{n+1}})^n=n^{n^{n+2}}$ has to be blue. However, $(n^n)^{n^n+1}=n^{n^{n+2}}$ has to be red, contradiction.

May someone help me find a counterexample to $N=n^{n^{n+2}}-1$ with $n=2$?

Comment: It may help to provide a brief summary of the logic/arguments used to attain your estimate for $N$

Comment: Just did, thanks for suggesting that.

Comment: $65536$ is confirmed as the smallest *nice* number.